# RewriteCond with negative conditions

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I'm trying to rewrite all `www.site.com/hello to www.site.com/index.php?p=hello`
and it works with the following code (in `.htaccess`):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ /index.php?p=$1
```

But I want to keep the old links working so `www.site.com/?p=hello` will stay `www.site.com/?p=hello`

I've tried the following code but it won't work

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\?p=)
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ /index.php?p=$1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found an answer.

The mistake was trying to get the `GET` parameters with `REQUEST_URI`. The right usage should be with `QUERY STRING` like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(p=.*)$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ /index.php?p=$1
```